# DBUnit Data Export

Tags: dbunit

Does anyone know if dbunit has the power to export specific data from multiple tables at once based on a sql statement, as can be done by using dbunit's QueryDataSet class to export data from a single table based on a sql statement, [as can been seen here](http://www.dbunit.org/faq.html#extract).

James

Answer (score 5):

http://jailer.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can. All you need is to call addTable(...) method to collect data to QueryDataSet and just export it by FlatXmlDataSet.write(...)

```
QueryDataSet partialDataSet = new QueryDataSet(connection);
partialDataSet.addTable(tableName1, "select * from " + tableName1);
partialDataSet.addTable(tableName2, "select * from " + tableName2);
partialDataSet.addTable(tableName3, "select * from " + tableName3);

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Noname.dataset");
FlatXmlDataSet.write(ratingDataSet, fos);
```